# Visual Studio 2017 Community Network (loopback) isolation

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sockets, networking

I developp a server/client in C++ (UWP) on visual studio.

My server work fine. If i try to connect from my debian, it works fine. But if I try on the same machine (on loopback address) the connexion doesn't work.

After many research, i've read that Visual Studio has a Network Isolation which block the connexion from the same machine. But it's possible to disable this isolation ?

Comment: What interfaces are your server program listening to? "Network isolation" seems to be something used by virtual environments, not something when you're running directly on the host. It could also be a firewall issue. But unless we can see some code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), of both the client and server, *and* knows what errors you get when trying to connect, we will not be able to help you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets

The problem is explain here. "the system forbids establishing socket connections (Sockets or WinSock) between two UWP apps running on the same machine via either the local loopback address (127.0.0.0) or explicitly specifying the local IP address."

Comment: You don't mention UWP anywhere in your question. That's pretty crucial and important information that should be in the question body. Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes I'm sorry. I've edit my post.